# Unzip an event stream of tuple 2 into two streams

Tags: haskell, reactive-banana

In reactive-banana, given `Event t (a, b)`, how would you lead it to `(Event t a, Event t b)`?

`Traversable#sequence` seems to solve it with some instance of `Monad` for `(,)` provided, but `Event t` is only `Functor`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
import Control.Applicative

unzipEvent :: Event t (a, b) -> (Event t a, Event t b)
unzipEvent = liftA2 (,) (fmap fst) (fmap snd)
```

Notes:

- The `liftA2 (,)` is general-purpose, as it is merely using the `Applicative` instance of functions. In this case, an equivalent alternative to it would be `(&&&)` from `Control.Arrow`. There is also a less fancy alternative, `\e -> (fst <$> e, snd <$> e)`.
- Even if `Event t` was `Traversable`, `sequenceA` wouldn't help. The `Functor` and `Applicative` instances for pairs [are parametrised only on the second component of the pair](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/src/GHC-Base.html#line-307). You'd end up with a `(a, Event t b)` result type, not to mention the `Monoid` constraint on `a`.

Comment: Thank you @duplode again for your answer, also I really appreciate your in-depth notes. I will look up `Arrow` as I've been interested in it.

Comment: The `liftA2 (,)` is a red herring, this is just `unzipEvent e = (fst <$> e, snd <$> e)` written point-free.

Comment: Thank you @Cactus for the easier looking solution! It was a good experience to follow types of the original combination tho.

Comment: @Cactus Quite a bit, indeed. It's just that my first impulse was doing `fmap fst &&& fmap snd`, but as `Control.Arrow` is arguably even more of a red herring I switched to the other point-free spelling.

Comment: Just a relative quick question; how would you go backward, `(Event t a, Event t b) -> Event t (a, b)`? I tried with `liftA2` but `Event t` is not `Applicative` @duplode

Comment: @RyoichiroOka Ugly, but should work: `fmap (\(Left x, Right y) -> (x, y)) . uncurry (unionWith (\(x,_) (y,_) -> (x, y))) . (fmap (dup . Left) *** fmap (dup . Right))`, with `dup x = (x, x)`. I wrote point-free for space; you'll likely prefer a less compact version. `(***)` is from Control.Arrow, and `unionWith` is the one from reactive-banana. For the final extraction from `Either` (unsafe in principle, but here we know it will work) you can use `fromLeft` and `fromRight` from `Data.Either.Combinators` in the `either` package. If the types are equal you don't need the `Either` tricks.

Comment: Thank you a lot again @duplode :) I will be posting some more questions and I hope you're still around

Comment: Small correction: it should be `fromLeft'` and `fromRight'` instead of `fromLeft` and `fromRight` in the comment just above.